# PHP Include echos '1'

Tags: php, include, echo

```
<?=include("inc/c.php")?>
```

Spits out 1 despite it being full of strings and no echo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove the `=` sign. It makes PHP echo whatever `include()` returns.

```
<?php
include("inc/c.php");
?>
```

Comment: I don't like using <?php include(""); ?> takes up to much characters. Is there not a way around this.

Comment: @TheBlackBenzKid, What???  Really?  `<?php` is really too much for you to type?  You shouldn't use short open tags anyway, as they aren't enabled on all servers.  If you want a short version, you can often use `<?`, but I don't recommended it, as again, it won't work on all servers, and for good reason.

Comment: I am worried about characters and app speed. <?=include("inc/c.php")?> was less then <?php include ("inc/c.php"); ?> - every character counts for my app. Thanks though.

Comment: If keeping the number of characters you have to type to an absolute minimum is of such critical importance, then consider using include "inc/c.php" without the brackets

Comment: Yes because things that are parsed SERVER SIDE (and then cached) are totally going to make your app slower for the client...

Comment: Yes indeed, you don't use to use `<?php`, you can use `<?` if you want. But if your concern about that is speed, then it is probably misplaced. The time difference in file reading speed and parsing speed between `<?` and `<?php` is insignificant.

Comment: Arrogant as ever. @Col.Shrapnel

Answer (score 6):

You're seeing the result of the `include()` function.  It returns `true` because it succeeded, and you see `1`, as that is the string representation of `true`.

If you want the text of that document, you can use [`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) or similar.

Comment: It's an interesting and often overlooked quirk actually. You can put a `return` in the main body of a file you include to make the `include` and `require` functions return values. If `c.php` contained `return "Happy string is happy. Hello World!"` it would actually give output. (You probably already knew it, but others may not)

Comment: @TheBlackBenzKid, Why? It wasn't a very good question.  In fact... it isn't even a question, just a statement of something you're seeing.  Please see the FAQ for what is considered a good question here.

Comment: Please if you can up vote some of my questions. Sure it was a mistake and I am sorry for it, I really like this community but I have been banned from questions due to negative points. I didnt do it on purpose. Just learning and clearly a naive approach. Appreciate you listening.

Comment: @TheBlackBenzKid, You realize you can edit your old questions, right?  It's really simple.  Follow the FAQ.  Write questions with the guidelines found in that FAQ.  This isn't about a lack of knowledge, it is about taking the time and effort to ask the right questions.  You'll find it is a skill that you are going to need in any field.  I up-vote good questions.  I do not up-vote bad questions.